# Match groups with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to create a regular expression for that :

My regular expression : `/^(\d+)[&]|[&](\d+)|(\d+)/g`

**Tests with desired results :**

1. `1501` : 1501
2. `1501&&15011` : 1501, 15011
3. `1501;or;15011` : 1501, 15011
4. `1501;OR;15011` : 1501, 15011
5. `>=1501;OR;15011` : 15011
6. `1501;OR;>=15011` : 1501
7. `>=15011` : null

But it seem's not working with `str.match()` in Javascript.

Comment: Why not `'1501&&15011'.split('&&');`?

Comment: Because the test could be `1501` or `15011&&15001` or `1501;OR;15011`...

Comment: so why not just `split('[^\d]+')`? to split on non digit characters

Comment: Why not just `/\d+/`?

Comment: Because `>=1501` should be `null` and `>=1501;OR;15011` should be `15011`.

Comment: Why not just get the digits from a line and make test against which is greater in your code?

Comment: Only `Tests with desired results` is not enough, what is the condition/criteria?

Comment: I'd like to get only digits preceded/ended by `&` or `;`. And I'd like to get only unique digits. And I don't want to get digits preceded by a char.

Comment: Shouldn't case 6 be `1501;OR;<=15011`? If not I don't understand the meaning of your `>=` characters.

Comment: Yes any chars before `15011` could be entered..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
[;&](\d+)|^(\d+)[&;]?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qC6zT3/3)

you can get values with captured groups 1 and 2.

Comment: It doesn't work `'>=1501;OR;15011'.match(/[;&](\d+)|^(\d+)[&;]?/g)` : `;15011`, the result should be `15011`.

Comment: @tonymx227 as I wrote in answer, _you can get values with captured groups 1 and 2_, not directly with `match()`

Comment: Ok so is there any other function?

Comment: @tonymx227 check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yfL4fL66/), it is done on string with all exemplary values you gave, but it should work with every separate line also

Comment: the `RegEx.exec(str)` method search `str` String for pattern `RegEx`, end returns array of matched values, then you can get matched groups (fragment matched by regex parts in paratheses) by geting element of array on given index (group 1 on index 1, etc., where index 0 will give you whole match, so result would be like with `match()` method). If in given string there is no match for some groups, it will return `undefined`, this is why I filter it out before displaying

Comment: Thank you, that's ok for me ;)